# Converting a txt file to string, then to array and then printing each word of the array

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, text

I am trying to convert a text file into a string, then into an array and then finaly print each of the values (words) into separate 'a' holders.

The .txt file contains one line of text.

I have tried it through a for loop, like so:

```
    $lines = file_get_contents('test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    $words = explode(" ", $lines);

    for ($x = 1; $x >= 100; $x++){
        print '<a id="word$x">'$words[$x]'</a>';
    }
```

But that doesnt work. I am sure that I am just missing something basic, but I have tried and failed so many times, that I need others opinions and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, don't forget about string concatenation: `print '<a id="word'.$x.'">'.$words[$x].'</a>';`

If you need more, than only 100 words use `$x < count($words)` in your for

Comment: Worked perfectly ! I will check this answer as correct. Ps: Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use <= instead of >=

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++){
    print '<a id="word$x">'$words[$x]'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sprinf](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.sprintf.php), it's much easier to read.

```
$lines = file_get_contents('test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$words = explode(" ", $lines);

for ($x = 1; $x >= 100; $x++){
  echo sprintf('<a id="word%s">%s</a>', $word, $words[$x]);
}
```

---

But if you don't want to, you can simply concatenate the values.

```
echo '<a id="word' . $x . '">' . $words[$x] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to use explicit `for` loops.

```
$lines = file_get_contents('test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$words = explode(" ", $lines);
$words = array_slice($words, 0, 100);

foreach ($words as $index => $word) {
    print "<a id=\"word$x\">$word</a>";
}
```

Also, **be aware array indexing starts with `0` not `1`**. If you do `$x = 1` you will end up losing the first word!

If you want to print all words, just lose the `$words = array_slice($words, 0, 100);`. Read more about `array_slice` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: Yes I forgot that arrays take the first value as 0, going from front-end development into php has creates some struggles along the way...Thanks tho